# What is the equivalent to Scientific Linux Users as a professional trouble shooting email list for Ubuntu?

Tags: community, mailing-list

All of my Linux machines, servers and laptop/workstations, were running Enterprise Linux under the Scientific Linux distro from Fermilab/Cern.

With the demise of that distro (no SL8), we weighed our alternatives and have elected Ubuntu LTS.  The machine from which I am posting this is a mobile workstation ("professional" laptop -- HP Zbook) now running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

With Red Hat, as with SuSE, the only lists available to those who do not license the product (technically, the installable "supported" port/distro) is not the same as the SL Users list that regularly have other experienced professionals posting and responding.

When it became apparent that some of the current non-beta production releases of applications we needed were no longer compatible with SL 7, but needed EL 8, the switch to Ubuntu LTS was undertaken.  Is there any list other than this website that is the equivalent of the SL Users list that had answers from the professional paid maintainers of SL (at Fermilab) and from those who maintained EL repositories (e.g., ELrepo)?

Thank you any information. I am not allowed to post this to META where I suspect the question belongs because I do not have a 5 or higher. Take care.  Stay safe.

Comment: What exactly do you want from the list? Paid support? Answers from Canonical employees?

Comment: _“I am not allowed to post this to META where I suspect the question belongs”_ No, your question belongs here on the main [ubuntu.se] site.

Answer (score 5):

The hub for Ubuntu development is [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). I do not know whether it will meet your needs, or if there is anything closer to what you want. You can take [their tour](https://launchpad.net/+tour/index) to explore. There are [Teams](https://help.launchpad.net/Teams) which have mailing lists, and [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/) which has Q&A with the participation of developers.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your topic. [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization. [Bioinformatics Q&A](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) is a question and answer site for people interested in bioinformatics.

If your question does not fall into one of these categories try either Ask Ubuntu if your question is about using software in Ubuntu or Stack Overflow if it's about programming. If your other questions at Ask Ubuntu are any indication your current interests are about evenly split between Ask Ubuntu and Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm a user at three of the four Q&A sites that I mentioned in this answer. If you're interested in the computational aspects of other categories it may help to browse all sites of the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) and see if you can find a site that is specific to your question.

Comment: It appears my question was not clear.    too long by 1030 (now 1304) characters is what appeared about this reply (it appears that only comments are allowed, not a dialog reply –  if a dialog reply is allowed, what is the command/”point and click”?).   Hence, I am splitting this comment if possible into multiple comments. The SL Users list maintained by Fermilab was not one of the developers internal lists (that also were available), but for technical questions across the board.  To be continued.

Comment: Comment continued.  From what I understand, if UCSF Chimera (that I use) does not work or properly function on Ubuntu, there is a bioinformatics "list", etc.  The questions posted to SL users list were sometimes that detailed (e.g., does anybody have a working port of application X?) or issues such as why the ELRepo NVIDIA driver (not nouveau) was not working, etc.  It also allowed one to use regular email (e.g., a Thunderbird interface), not this very small dialog box that simply scrolls out of reading (and thus makes editing much more difficult).   To be continued again.

Comment: Continued part 3.  Thus, I found out that even the SNAP for a particular application would not work on any EL7 because Linux is a monolithic kernel, not a Mach type microkernel architecture, and thus the basic gcc libraries were incompatible -- a SNAP does not fully encapsulate the system environment.  This reality was one of the reasons for migrating to Ubuntu, currently 20.4.x LTS.  To be continued.

Comment: Continued part 4.  The other reason is that Ubuntu LTS allows upgrade from LTS major release N to N-next (e.g., 18.X LTS to 20.Y LTS), whereas SL7 to EL8 requires a complete "fresh" full install (although special "games" could be played with partitions -- but this does not always work). From the responses, I take it that there is no such Ubuntu LTS "professional users" list.  How does one find the various lists that exist?  (I am having a problem with the on-machine microphone; a USB external microphone works well.)  Take care, stay safe. End response with clarification questions.

Comment: Chimera support so far on Ubuntu is basically nonexistent so far and there's [How to install ESA SNAP on Ubuntu Linux](https://www.gis-blog.com/how-to-install-esa-snap-on-ubuntu-linux/). Somebody at Ask Ubuntu should volunteer to provide these applications with better support comparable to the way is was done with SL. I have the necessary skills to support these applications on the Ubuntu/software side, but I do not have the necessary skills to support them on the scientific side. I don't consider myself to be qualified to support these packages w/o taking online equivalent of college courses.

Comment: In terms of upgrading from LTS to a newer LTS Ubuntu is aggressively maintained by Canonical and free support at Ask Ubuntu is available. When I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 existing bugs in 18.04 disappeared, probably due to that fact that my workstation is new (bought in 2020).

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat? appeared when I was going to respond to karel. What is "chat" on these lists?  Is it interactive or archival (the SL users list is archival and "searchable" until Fermilab deletes the archive once SL is fully "dead").  Note that UCSF provides a port of Chimera current that seems to be fully functional under 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114038/discussion-between-karel-and-yasha-karant).

Comment: still no dialog box, attempting to insert screenshot -- not allowed .  How do I get you a screen shot of what I currently see, with a fresh reload of the chat page, using Firefox stock current?  Take care.  Stay safe.

Comment: Click the row of three dots in the Firefox address bar and select **Take a Screenshot**.